# Install PIA for Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012, pia

I installed Office 2007 on Windows Server 2012 R2. But failed to install PIA for office2007.

That seems PIA for office2007 do not support Windows Server 2012.

So for using PIA on Windows Server 2012 R2 , what is the version of PIA and Office should I use.

Please help me. Thank you !

Comment: "failed to install" is not an appropriate problem description.

Comment: Crosspost to Stack Overflow for Japanese: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/34146/windows-server-2012-r2%E3%81%A7pia%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF